# gnome shell theme disabled

Tags: gnome

Can someone help me resolve this issue.

I am new to ubuntu. Let me know what additional information you need.

```
xemex@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get install -f` . This should solve the issue.

If not. Please edit your question and post output of the above command.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the `gnome-shell-extensions-common` package for functionality purpose as

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme gnome-shell-extensions-common`